# Changing colour of text in table cell with php and js

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a form which i want the days to change colour at certain milestones. 
I have the JS but it only works for the first cell and not the others. Any ideas how to loop the js so it changes every cell called DAYS in the table?

Ive put the ID after  in the table but probably wrong .

```
$(function () {
    // Score Color
    var score = parseInt($('#DAYS').text().trim());
    var color = 'red';
    if (!isNaN(score)) {
        if (score >= 40) {
            color = 'orange';
        }
        if (score >= 60) {
            color = 'green';
        }
        $('#DAYS').css('color', color);
    }
});

PHP table: 
echo"<td id=DAYS>".$applicant_card['DAYS']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DrRoach told,we should use `class` instead of `id` if we are targetting multiple items. As `id` always points to only one unique element.

So you can give `class` as `DAYS` instead of `id` and run through each element using `each()` to give them respectice color.

**Sample Code**

```js
$(function () {
   $('.DAYS').each(function(){
    var score = parseInt($(this).text().trim());
    var color = 'red';
    if (!isNaN(score)) {
        if (score >= 40) {
            color = 'orange';
        }
        if (score >= 60) {
            color = 'green';
        }
        $(this).css('color', color);
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
PHP table: 
<table>
<tr><td class=DAYS>34</td></tr>
<tr><td class=DAYS>44</td></tr>
<tr><td class=DAYS>74</td></tr>
<tr><td class=DAYS>23</td></tr>
<tr><td class=DAYS>54</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this include what it would it look like if in a dynamic table that populates from the line of php i originally gave?

Comment: Yeah...just gave some dummy table value to show the sample

Comment: Great thanks... with risk of getting down arrowed. What is best book/ref  i could use for this info without having to ask you pro's!

Comment: If its about HTML & JavaScript. I guess Mozilla docs are best https://developer.Mozilla.org/en/docs/Web

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `id=DAYS` in the echo to `class=DAYS`. Ids can only reference one DOM element whereas classes can reference multiple.

```
$(".DAYS").each(function() {
  var score = parseInt($(this).text().trim());
  var color = 'red';
  if (!isNaN(score)) {
    if (score >= 40) {
        color = 'orange';
    }
    if (score >= 60) {
        color = 'green';
    }
    $(this).css('color', color);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice one that worked on all the numbers,,i change the # to a '.' in script. All the numbers are green though,, i was expecting different colours for different values as the script says red orange etc

Comment: Ahh sorry, my change will set all rows to the same colour as the first value. Please see my edit.

Comment: Sorry but the numbers just came back unchanged(black),,  ankits worked for me. thx for reply

Comment: its been a long day ... apologies

Comment: Haha no worries :)

Comment: What is best book/ref i could use for this info without having to ask you pro's!

Answer (score 0):

Just use "" change

`PHP table: 
 echo"<td id="DAYS">".$applicant_card['DAYS']."</td>";`

thats all