# Method for html table cell conditional formatting for php drawn SQL values

Tags: php

I have a table that is full of percentages, my values are pulled from an SQL database. I want to change a css element (bg color, color, etc.) depending on the value drawn from SQL. E.g. 0-10% = red, 20-20% = orange, etc. I saw this [Changing colour of text in table cell with php and js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462933/changing-colour-of-text-in-table-cell-with-php-and-js) but I think my insertion of the % prevents it from working. This is my table code, I have no other code yet.

```
<tr>
<th>Jan</th>
<th>Feb</th> 
<th>Mar</th>
<th>Apr</th>
<th>May</th> 
<th>Jun</th>
<th>Jul</th>
<th>Aug</th> 
<th>Sep</th>
<th>Oct</th>
<th>Nov</th> 
<th>Dec</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="rating"><?php echo $wor['rjan'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rfeb'];?>%/td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rmar'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rapr'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rjun'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rjul'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['raug'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rsep'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['roct'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rnov'];?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $wor['rdec'];?>%</td>
</tr>
```

Rather then a solution to a specific problem I'm asking for a suggestion of a method.One way I thought to do it is to have a long php ifelse statement for each sql field that changes the style of class of each cell. However this would require writing the statement out 12 times, which seems like a long way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to use so many `if-else` or `switch-case` blocks to get the right percentage range and the corresponding color. Use a simple a function like this:

```
function getColor($percentage){ 
    $perArray = array(10 => 'red', 20 => 'orange', 30 => 'green', ...);
    if ($percentage % 10)
        $percentage = $percentage + (10 - $percentage % 10);
    return $perArray[$percentage];
}
```

In the above function, `$perArray` array would be interpreted like this:

- `10 => 'red'` means a percentage value of 0-10 would be assigned red color
- `20 => 'orange'` means a percentage value of 11-20 would be assigned orange color
- `30 => 'green'` means a percentage value of 21-30 would be assigned green
- and so on

And this is how you should call the `getColor()` function for each table row:

```
<tr>
    <th>Jan</th>
    ...
    <th>Dec</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color:<?php echo getColor($wor['rjan']); ?>;"><?php echo $wor['rjan'];?>%</td>
    <td style="color:<?php echo getColor($wor['rfeb']); ?>;"><?php echo $wor['rfeb'];?>%</td>
    ...
    <td style="color:<?php echo getColor($wor['rdec']); ?>;"><?php echo $wor['rdec'];?>%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a PHP function that will accept the percentage as an argument, put it through several if-statements and return the desired color.

The function can look like:

```
function get_color($num_str) {
    $num = intval($num_str);

    if ($num < 10) return 'red';
    if ($num < 20) return 'orange';
    // ...
}
```

And use of this function can then be:

```
<td class="<?php get_color($wor['rfeb']); ?>">
    <?php echo $wor['rfeb']; ?>%
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a function to do it. (Also the < is missing on the closing td on the rfeb row.)

For the html, make each row (obvious css classes could be used here too):

```
<td style="backbround-color: <?= color($wor['rmar']) ?>;"><?php echo $wor['rmar'];?>%</td>
```

the add a function to the php

```
<?php
function color($amt) {
    switch (floor($amt/10)) {
        case 0: return 'red';
        case 1: return 'orange';
        // ...
        default: return 'transparent';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd only have to write it out twelve times because you're explicitly echoing the `<td>` for each month. If you put it into a loop instead, you can write the logic for the formatting *once*.

The other answers that suggest creating a function to determine the formatting you'll use can be combined with this. (Putting that logic into a function seems like a good idea to me, but you'll still need to call the function 12 times.)

I suggest having that function return the name of a predefined (by you, or some CSS framework, e.g. bootstrap, etc.) CSS class that you can apply to the cells rather than using it to explicitly set background color, etc. in an inline style. I just made up a name (`format_percentage_cell`) for example, but whatever you want to call it, you know. And the other answers have some good ideas for starting points for your implementation.

```
<tr>
<?php foreach ($wor as $month): ?>
    <td class="<?= format_percentage_cell($month) ?>"><?= $month ?>%</td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only want a sugestion, I would do the following:

You only have to calculate the bytes. 255 is a maximum on *each* (3 in total excluding the alpha channel) color range this would be your 100% in percentages. This can easily be applied if you add a style attribute to the `tr` element with the `rgb()` function.

So if you want red (lowbound) to green (highbound) you only have to do the following:

```
function yourfunction($percentage){
  return 'rgb('. round((255 / 100) * $percentage) .', '. round((255 / 100) * (100 - $percentage)).', 0)';
}
```

So adjust the function to your color likings for example red to green and directly print the value out to the `<tr style="color: <?= yourfunction($percentage)?>" >value</tr>`

Comment: The `rgb` args might need to be flipped, can't test it right now.